# How to put background-color behind text-underline?

Tags: html, css

I am running in to a small problem when applying a `background-color` on the element `<mark>` inside a `<h2>`.

**Current Status**:

[image: http://jmp.sh/byQ2bMM]

**How it should be**:

[image: http://jmp.sh/vhpS5u5]

**Markup**

```
<h2>Wednesday, 06 of <mark>January</mark> 2016</h2>
```

Ultimately, the background of `<mark>` should be behind the text-underline of the `<h2>`. Played around with `z-index` but does not work. I assume because `<mark>`is inside `<h2>`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's already behind underline, by default. https://jsfiddle.net/L0ppmvph/ Doesn't it? Next time add jsfiddle or codepen example please.

Comment: @Denis I think he wants the margin of h2 also to be filled in that colour. That's at least what I could understand from the pictures.

Comment: I think the problem is by using horizontal `padding`.

Comment: I should have been clearer and add a jsfiddle. I am using border-bottom: 1px solid black; for the underline in order to get a nicer underline, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ajdwah9/ – and this is causing the problem. Any workaround?

Comment: Then remove the bottom padding of the `mark`? (or just use a smaller one so that it doesn't go bellow the h2 border)

Comment: That's not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlay a line using a pseudo element: https://jsfiddle.net/4ajdwah9/3/

```
mark::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 3px;
  background: black;
}
```

To work better with zooming as suggested, just change it slightly:

```
mark::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 3px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: @ThierryM. please check again the answer bellow. It's a much simpler solution and works well when zooming, while this one doesn't. And, if you have more text after the `mark`, the `mark` will still be underlined, which is not the desired effect. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/4ajdwah9/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4ajdwah9/2

Works after changing z-index.

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

mark {
    background: tomato;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It is a quick fix for the issue though. After using z-index: -1 it might hide in some cases.

Comment: I find your answer better than the accepted one. Yours uses just a single property to fix the issue, while the accepted one is more complex and doesn't work well when zooming (your does).